# Double becomes pointer when returned?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, types

I'm new to Cpp and I'm just trying to construct a very basic 'Circle' class. Below is my code

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo> 

class Circle { 
    
    private: 
    const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    double radius;
    double area; 
    double perimeter;  
    public: 
    void set_rad(double rad){ 
        radius = rad; 
        area = pi*pow(rad,2); 
        perimeter = 2*pi*rad;  
        
        
    }

    double get_attr() {
        double circle_attr[3] = {radius, area, perimeter}; 
        std::cout << typeid(circle_attr).name() << std::endl; 

        return *circle_attr; 
    }
}; 

int main(){ 
   
    Circle aCircle;
    aCircle.set_rad(5);
    aCircle.get_attr();
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs and behaves as expected. However, if, in the return line to the method `get_attr`, I replace `*circle_attr` with `circle_attr` , then I get the error `cannot convert 'double*' to 'double' in return`. However, `circle_attr` is already an array of doubles. That's what I intialised it as and it's what Cpp is telling me, since when I call `typeid(circle_attr).name()` I get back `A3_d`, which I assume is short for Array3_double. So what is going on here?

Comment: Ask yourself: is an array of doubles the same as a single double? As for why the compiler thinks your array is now a pointer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay

Comment: Sure, but how else would I declare a function if I want it to return an array of doubles?

Comment: If you can use C++11 or newer, you switch to using a `std::array`.  If you can't, make your own array class.  plain C arrays are kind of a second class citizen in the type system and should be avoided if you can to avoid issues like this.

Comment: Why not return a tuple instead?

Comment: I'm sure there are work arounds, but since I'm just getting familiar with C++ I thought it better to get to the bottom of it

Comment: This is the sort of thing I would use a `struct` for. There are several generic containers you can use, but `struct` allows you to give easily readable names to all of the members. Not so important once you have [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) in the recent C++ Standards, but if, like me, you're stuck to going old school, the added legibility is worth its weight in gold.

Comment: `std::tuple<double, double, double>` or `struct attr_result { double r, a, p; };`

Comment: " if I want it to return an array of doubles" --> code cannot return a raw _array_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual issue you're having is the attempt to return a C-array from a function. That's not a thing that can be done. If you want, the smallest possible change would be to change your function to look like this:

```cpp
#include <array>

// [...]

std::array<double, 3> get_attr() {
        std::array<double, 3> circle_attr{radius, area, perimeter}; 
        std::cout << typeid(circle_attr).name() << std::endl; 

        return circle_attr; 
    }
```

You stated that your function was supposed to return **A** double, and then you tried returning an array of doubles, or really just the radius in your case.

`std::array` is a bit of a mess, though, since the size is part of the type information.

Here's your code, with some tweaks to get it more in line with C++ and also completely rewriting your `get_attr()` function.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>  // CHANGED: Needed for structured binding usage in get_attr()

class Circle {
 private:
  const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
  double radius = 0.0;  // CHANGED: Kept the default member initialization going
  double area = 0.0;
  double perimeter = 0.0;

 public:
  Circle() = default;  // CHANGED: Added constructors
  Circle(double r)
      : radius(r), area(pi * std::pow(radius, 2)), perimeter(2 * pi * radius) {}

  void set_rad(double rad) {
    radius = rad;
    area = pi * pow(rad, 2);
    perimeter = 2 * pi * rad;
  }

  // CHANGED: Using C++17 feature called structured bindings; also made function
  // const, since it shouldn't alter the data
  auto get_attr() const { return std::make_tuple(radius, area, perimeter); }
};

int main() {
  Circle aCircle(5.0);  // CHANGED: Now we can use constructors
  // aCircle.get_attr();  // NOTE: Didn't even try to save info anywhere
  auto [radius, area, perimeter] = aCircle.get_attr();
  std::cout << "Radius: " << radius << "\nArea: " << area
            << "\nPerimieter: " << perimeter << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Radius: 5
Area: 78.5398
Perimieter: 31.4159
```

We added constructors, which are a fundamental part of C++ OOP. You can see in `main()` how constructors allow us to initialize at the declaration site.

I also left one your original lines in `main()` to note that even if `get_attr()` worked, you didn't save the info at all. So you wouldn't have had it anyway.

Your `get_attr()` function has been written to take advantage of a C++17 feature called [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding). It also takes advantage of another feature called [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), just to keep the one line in `get_attr()` succinct.

In order for you to test this, you'll need to add the `-std=c++17` flag to the compile command you're using. It's good practice to always specify the standard version you're using.